# Rails App: Is the README.md file and referred to images inside that file publicly accessible?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git

I want to confirm that the `README.md` file for my rails app, and the images I refer to inside that readme file, are *not* publicly accessible to users.

I want to of course be able to view the `README.md` file inside my private repo via Git as usual.  I just want to be sure that users can't access the readme file at all.

I never defined a route to the README file, so there is no *explicit* route to the README file within `config/routes.rb`.  And as far as I am aware: rails does not auto-generate some *implicit* route to the README file either.  So: Users have no way to access the readme file.

I'm wondering if perhaps rails does in fact implicitly create some route to the readme file.  Thus: there exists some url to the readme file that I do not know about. Ex:

```
www.myapp.com/path-to-readme-file
```

Or maybe the rails app makes the readme file accessible to users by some other means which I do not know about.

**My implementation of a README file with images inside my rails app**:

```
# README.md
Text inside a README file.  Below is an image.  I don't want any of this viewable by users that access my app online

![Image that I want to be sure is not publically accessible][img1]

[img1]: /readme_images/test.png
```

I store the images I refer to within the `README` document at the root of the app within a directory called: `readme_images`.  Currently I only have that `test.png` image:

[image: readme_images directory]

And I push to git and when I look at my private repo the README file formatting and images inside the README file renders great.

I just want to be sure that Rails does not make that README file and the referred to images inside the readme file accessible to users through some url, or some other way I do not know about.

If rails does happen to implicitly make the README file accessible to users: how do I disable it?

Comment: [Protect image download](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21110248/3098330) check this out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do `rake routes` to see all your accessible pages. As long as the images not in your public or one of your assets directories(which they aren't, based on your picture), it won't be accessible. Rails does not make a public link to the README.md. Your files are hidden from the public.