# How to reuse base64 image repeatedly in HTML file

Tags: javascript, html, static, base64

I have an HTML file that will be portable to distribute to clients.  It has an index of documents.  I want a PDF or Word icon for each document but I don't want to repeat the base64 string 30 times if I can avoid it.  How should I do this?  Javascript is okay, but my goals are simplicity and portability.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The other answer using CSS gives the right idea, but it is not compatible with all browsers. The `content` property of the CSS is only allowed in the pseudo-elements `::before` and `::after`. The `img` tag with a class with a content property is empty. The browsers have no obligation to display it. Chrome displays it nevertheless (incorrectly).

To make this work for all browsers, use for example the `::before` on an empty span:

```css
span.word-icon::before {
  content: url(data:image/gif;base64,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);
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>  
    <p><span class="word-icon"></span>Paragraph with icon.</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

You can also attach it directly to `p::before`.

Answer (score 17):

Try using CSS class

```css
img.word-icon {
  content: url(data:image/gif;base64,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);
  width: 32px;  
  height: 32px;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>  
    <img class="word-icon">foo
    <img class="word-icon">bar
    <img class="word-icon">
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Oh now this is brilliant. I hadn't thought of CSS.  Thanks!

Comment: This is the right idea. Added a solution compatible with most browsers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44710590/1667977

Answer (score 5):

You can use a CSS variable.

In the `<head>` section of the page, name and define the variable and a class to use it:

```css
:root {
    --img-123: url(data:null;base64,iVBORw………); /* your image data here */
}

.img-123 {
    background-blend-mode: normal;
    background-clip: content-box;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    background-image:var(--img-123);
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-origin: content-box;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

In the `<body>` section of the page, use the image repeatedly via element style section or CSS classes. The SVG data creates a transparent image through which to see the content.

```
<img 
  class="img-123" 
  src="data:image/svg+xml,&lt;svg xmlns=&quot;http://www.w3.org/2000/svg&quot; width=&quot;16&quot; height=&quot;16&quot;&gt;&lt;rect fill-opacity=&quot;0&quot;/&gt;&lt;/svg&gt;"
>
```

I observed this technique in the output of the open source Firefox / Chrome extension [SingleFile](https://github.com/gildas-lormeau/SingleFile). There might be ways to simplify the CSS and to avoid using SVG.

Comment: I'm the author of SingleFile. The purpose of the SVG in SingleFile is to give a size to the image without altering the CSS. So, I confirm you can avoid SVG if setting the width and the height of the image with CSS is not an issue for you.

Answer (score 1):

create a script to insert it into the images.  I purposely put the script code inline since you're sending a single HTML file:

```html
<img alt="pdf"/>
<img alt="pdf"/>
<img alt="pdf"/>
<img alt="pdf"/>
<img alt="pdf"/>
<img alt="pdf"/>
<script>
  var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++){
  images[i].src = "data:image/png;base64,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";
}
</script>
```

Comment: The application is the difficulty. I could do it in JQuery but I don't want any libraries or separate files.

Comment: Updated my answer @Devil'sAdvocate.  Just another approach.

Comment: This is what I was expecting, thanks for the update.  But I prefer the CSS solution.

Comment: I've heard from different sources that using 'content' in CSS is bad since it separates the purposes of CSS, HTML and Javascript.  CSS is supposed to be for presentation only, HTML for content, and Javascript for interactivity or DOM manipulation.  Honestly, I don't think it really matters in your specific case, and i'm not an expert, just what the general consensus in the programming community is from what I've read:  http://www.karlgroves.com/2013/08/26/css-generated-content-is-not-content/

Comment: I respect that argument but I was never a fan.  Of course I also mix my food on my plate.