# how can i hidden and prevent download source of css, js?

Tags: jquery, css

how can I **hidden** and **prevent download** source of **css**, **js** and **images** files in my website ?
like this web site:

www[dot]sales.4080.ir/themes/corporate3/index.html

I want to protect my template and prevent download my theme js,css and images files,
I thought this work was impossible but i saw this website :

www[dot]sales.4080.ir/themes/corporate3/index.html

and I understood that work is possible and I wanna help me that how to do them?

for example :

1- http://sales.4080.ir/themes/corporate3/js/limite/limite.js

2- http://sales.4080.ir/Themes/corporate3/css/menuResize/menuResize.css

The files that I mentioned above, neither of them can not download...
and I want to do like that trick...

please help me...

thanks...

Comment: DNS not found, can't access the page at all...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Protect image download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21110130/protect-image-download)

Answer (score 0):

Normally you can use file permission to do that, but if you want to prevent download to you're css and js file, i think thats same like you want browser to ignore that file on you're website, how to say this, i dont think you can do that, you need browser to access that file, not ignore it,
But if you want to prevent someone using ctrl+u or right click, i think you can find much article on google.
Btw, that's just my opinion. Maybe someone can explain :v