# How to prevent after opening a file from html link(From downloading or right click prevent)

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have an HTML code that contains a tag, a tag contains a link for my server uploaded file path whenever I click on the link that is redirecting to other tab showing file like image(should be viewable) and also giving the file to save on right mouse click. The downloading from browser I need to prevent. Any Plugin is there to prevent from the download.

```
<a href='http://localhost/admin/file/file.png'>File</a>
```

Comment: Regardless of available plugins...what about if user takes a screenshot of your image?

Comment: @B001ᛦ: print key also can be disabled by using javascript, isnt it? i suggest to use **IMAGE WATER MARK** and chil

Comment: that is ok, first I am working on to prevent download.

Comment: _print key also can be disabled..._ Sure, but you don't need the print key at all... there are many screenshot addons instead @devpro

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Protect image download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21110130/protect-image-download)

Comment: @B001ᛦ: agreed its true

Comment: what about mobile screen shot, keys... :)

Comment: I like the idea with the watermark

Comment: Using **WATER MARK ON IMAGE** is a good idea something like shutterstock

Answer (score 0):

```
document.addEventListener('contextmenu', event => event.preventDefault());
```

Try this it will prevent right click and you can also use watermark
and also you can't block print screen

Answer (score 0):

Hope it helps.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    document.onkeydown = function(e) {
        if (e.ctrlKey &&
            (e.keyCode === 67 ||
                e.keyCode === 86 ||
                e.keyCode === 85 ||
                e.keyCode === 117)) {
            return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
};
$(document).keypress("u",function(e) {
    if(e.ctrlKey)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
});

});
```